# How can I add my extension API into civicrm API?

Tags: api

I create a extension with API but I want to add in API 3 (i.e.on civicrm portal in support->developer ->API explorer.)[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you've added an api in the extension, it will be automatically seen in the API explorer, provided -

- The extension is enabled.
- The API is created as per https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-api
- The api file need to be under `/path/to/extension/api/v3/your_file.php` which is auto-created if you've followed the steps in the above documentation